# I can't make a crud based search form. Why it is not working?

Tags: sql, search, crud, web2py

My code:

models/db.py

```
....
dbmy = DAL('mysql://user:user@localhost/test',migrate_enabled=False)
dbmy.define_table('Firewall', Field('disabled','text'),
                            Field('src_port_first','integer'),
                            Field('src_port_last','integer'),
                            Field('port_first','integer'),
                            Field('port_last','integer'),
                            Field('type','text'),
                            Field('Src_op','text'),
                            Field('src_ipaddr_first','text'),
                            Field('src_ipaddr_last','text'),
                            Field('src_netmask','text'),
                            Field('Dst_op','text'),
                            Field('dst_ipaddr_first','text'),
                            Field('dst_ipaddr_last','text'),
                            Field('dst_netmask','text'),
                            Field('Action','text'))
dbmy.commit()
```

controllers/select.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gluon.tools import Crud
crud=Crud(dbmy)
def search():
    return dict(form=crud.search(dbmy.Firewall))
```

If I try to `127.0.0.1:8000/[app]/select/search/Firewall` URL, The page write this:

> invalid view (select/search.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your controller action returns a dictionary, web2y expects an associated view file -- in this case, it will look for /views/select/search.html. You must create that view.

Alternatively, you can enable the [generic.html view](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Generic-views) in this case. Note, in the scaffolding app, all generic views are enabled for local requests only, but disabled otherwise (due to security concerns).

You can also specify a different view via `response.view`.

Finally, given your controller code, there is no reason to add "Firewall" to your URL, as the `search` function is already hard coded to search the `db.Firewall` table (in fact, the `search` function completely ignores the "Firewall" in the URL).